# Dragon Ball Z (DBZ) and Dragon Ball (DB)

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball

Why in dragon ball z (DBZ) does it show bulma flying up to Kame's house, when in dragon ball (DB) Bora says that people have tried flying up there but the fuel tanks would run out not even half way up the tower. It doesn't make sense, doesn't that mean anyone can get up there now or what?

Comment: Perhaps because Bulma is Bulma (a genius) and can make a plane capable of flying there? I dont think there was ever given a reason for that

Answer (score 1):

in DB Bulma was a teenager on a summer vacation trying to find the dragon balls. and even though their technology is pretty high at the time I guess they don't have the **appropriate**  tech to reach there.
But in the early stages of DBZ we see people coming to earth from far away planets and bringing new technology with them. Bulma has grown in to an adult and is now more knowledgeable, and by having access to the space pod she figured out how it works.
Then we see Bulma gaining access to a Namekian space ship and seeing how she changed the language and used the space ship we could say she now has it's technology as well.
So if you can travel to outer space why wouldn't you be able to get to Kami house?
And I don't think anyone can go there now. Kami's house is considered a holy palace and I don't think Bulma would expose it to everyone. So even if she can go there, doesn't mean she will share the tech with everyone.

Answer (score -1):

The level of technology was always ambiguous in DB. Sometimes it felt like they were in the dark ages but at the same time capsules and androids existed. Still, it stands to reason that if Bulma has the iq and resources to solve space and time travel, there is probably no place too high in her own atmosphere for her to reach.